# A possible Iteration issue?

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, discord.py

I've decided to rewrite my code for a starboard module for my bot. 
I'm getting an issue when any reaction other than the star reaction is added to a post then the message is posted to starboard.

How it supposed to run is when a only a star emoji is added to the post it will add to starboard.

I'm not sure whether it is simple iteration but here is what I'm working with

```
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, member):
    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
        chan = get(guild.channels, name="starboard")
        if chan:
            for i in reaction.message.reactions:
                if i.emoji == '⭐':
                    return
                if reaction.message.author == member:
                    return
                if reaction.count < 1:
                    return
                embed=discord.Embed(color=0xff8000, description=reaction.message.content)
                embed.set_author(name=reaction.message.author.name, icon_url=reaction.message.author.avatar_url)
                if len(reaction.message.attachments) > 0:
                    embed.set_image(url=reaction.message.attachments[0]["url"])
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Posted in {reaction.message.channel.name}")
                embed.timestamp = dt.datetime.utcnow()
            await chan.send("New Star!", embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if i.emoji == '⭐':
    return
```

If the emoji is a star, stop the coroutine.  I think you're looking for something more along the lines of

```
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, member):
    chan = get(reaction.message.guild.channels, name="starboard")
    if not chan:
        return
    if reaction.emoji != '⭐':  # We only care about stars
        return
    if reaction.message.author == member: 
        return
    if reaction.count != 1: # Only the first time
        return
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0xff8000, description=reaction.message.content)
    embed.set_author(name=reaction.message.author.name, icon_url=reaction.message.author.avatar_url)
    if len(reaction.message.attachments) > 0:
        embed.set_image(url=reaction.message.attachments[0].url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Posted in {reaction.message.channel.name}")
    embed.timestamp = dt.datetime.utcnow()
    await chan.send("New Star!", embed=embed)
```

This posts a message to the starboard when someone uses a star to react for the first time. At the moment, if the first star comes from the messages author,l no amount of stars will allow it to be put on the starboard.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: `embed.set_image(url=reaction.message.attachments[0]["url"])
TypeError: 'Attachment' object is not subscriptable` I get this error with this.

Comment: Use `reaction.message.attachments[0].url` instead